# Bcrypt performance issue

Tags: java, performance, encryption, jvm, bcrypt

We are using Bcrypt implementation that comes with Spring security(v 3.1.3) on our web application. We have a limited number of users that have their password encrypted using bcrypt (we are still testing it).

When these users login to our site, it usually takes about 0.8 seconds for the user entered password to be encrypted (we use log rounds of 12 used for the encryption). At times we see the time spiking to more than 5 minutes.

At first we assumed it was related to the amount of traffic on our web servers but there are a number of scenarios where the traffic is similar and no performance issue was shown. We even had cases where bcrypt was very slow on off-peak hours. This performance issue is random and could not find any explanation why it is happening.

One additional point to mention is that I couldn't recreate this issue in local environment.

Our production system uses Java 7, with tomcat servers being our app servers with Linux OS.

I am not sure where to look anymore. Any suggestions or ideas to debug this differently would be very welcome.

Comment: Bcrypt is slow by design, but its run time should be predictable without such spikes. You should find a way to take thread dumps from your server to check whether it is indeed bcrypt math that causes these spikes or something else (like I/O or carefully misplaced synchronization).

Comment: We recently observed the same behavior with our own app (also Spring, also Java 7).  Did you discover any root cause or change that produced expected behavior again?

Comment: When something behaves normally most of the time, but randomly pauses sometimes, my first question is always whether it was the JVM. So, have you ruled out GC and any other pause factors?